# How do i implement an until loop in c#

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

I am making a simple Higher, Lower game and I want the game to continue until the right number is guessed or if the guesser wants to restart. What loop do I use and how would I implement it

my code is

```
Random RandomNumber = new Random();
int RandomNumber2 = RandomNumber.Next(1, 5);
//Console.WriteLine(RandomNumber2);

//want to insert loop here and it should end when the third else if is done

Console.WriteLine("Make Your Guess Now");
string UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
int UserInput2 = Convert.ToInt32(UserInput);

if (UserInput2 > RandomNumber2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your Number is to high");
}
else if (UserInput2 < RandomNumber2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your Number is too small");
}
else if (UserInput2 == RandomNumber2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Congrats on guessing the right number");
}
```

Comment: There are multiple constructors you could use to achieve this, but in your case a do-while loop sounds the most appropriate.

Comment: When you learn a traditional programming language, you learn about variables, types and conditional statements.  The next thing you learn (usually) is about loops.  Search for _"looping in c#"_ using a search engine and you should find some tutorials

Comment: The last `else` does not require the test `if (UserInput2 == RandomNumber2)`, since the other possibilities have already been treated above, it is the one left. I.e., when this case is executed `UserInput2` is always equal to `RandomNumber2`. Remember that else is only execute when the `if` part is not executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do it is to use a [do while loop (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/do).

Bute here, you can use an infinite loop and exit from it using a `break` statement. This allows you to break out of the loop from a condition tested inside the loop

```
...
Console.WriteLine("Make Your Guess Now");
while (true) {
    string UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
    int UserInput2 = Convert.ToInt32(UserInput);

    if (UserInput2 > RandomNumber2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your Number is too high. Make another guess");
    }
    else if (UserInput2 < RandomNumber2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your Number is too small. Make another guess");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Congrats on guessing the right number");
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that there is no need to test for `UserInput2 == RandomNumber2` in the last else, since the other cases have been treated above, this is the only possibility remaining. Note that an else-part is executed when the if-part is not executed and only then.

Answer (score 0):

Like said It think the best solution is

```
Do
{
  --if here
} While (userinput2==randomnumber2)
```

Comment: c# is case sensitive and he want to repeat as long as the guess was wrong. Therefore `do { ... } while (UserInput2 != RandomNumber2);` or better yet `while (true)` and then place a `break` in the last case.